# How to show Toast message inside thread?

Tags: android, toast, runtimeexception

I want to show `Toast` message inside thread.. but I am getting

```
RunTimeException:Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `android.os.Handler` instance to access the UI-thread from another thread:

For example:

```
class YourUI exends Activity {

    private Handler hm;

    @override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        // do stuff, and instantiate the handler
        hm = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message m) {
                // toast code
            }
        };
    }


    public Handler returnHandler(){
        return hm;
    }
}
```

In a non-UI thread, use this:

```
YourUI.getHandler().sendEmptyMeassage(0);
```

Comment: It's better to use hm.sendEmptyMessage(0); in the non-UI thread :)

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!!
Just one thing.. change `YourUI.getHandler().sendEmptyMeassage(0);` to `YourUI.returnHandler().sendEmptyMeassage(0);` to be coherent to the code you posted. But works perfect (+1)

Answer (score 11):

Try below code in your thread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {                
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                //Your toast code here
            }
        });
```

What happens that Thread is a non GUI thread and you can't access GUI element from non-GUI Threads